# How to estimate the value of this supremum?

Tags: real-analysis

Could you please guide me through how to estimate or calculate this supremum 
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left|x \cdot \arctan(nx)-x \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right|=?$$

Comment: What is $n$? Do you want the supremum as a function of $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that 
$$
\arctan x=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\pi}{2}=\int_\infty^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}
$$
to write
$$
\Bigl|x\,\arctan(nx)-\frac{\pi}{2}\,x\Bigr|=|x|\int_{nx}^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}.
$$
It is clear, as hinted to you by Harald, that as $x\to-\infty$, the above expression is not bounded.

Now I will make a wild guess: you are trying to prove that $x\,\arctan(n\,x)$ converges uniformly to $\pi\,x/2$ on $[0,\infty)$. In that case you do not need the exact value of the $\sup$; an upper bound might be enough. If $x>0$, then
$$
x\int_{nx}^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\le x\int_{nx}^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac{1}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Look at the case of large negative $x$ (assuming $n>0$). You might be surprised.